# show button when var abc = 0 else hide button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are similar queries but not exactly what I am looking for.

I need to display a registration button in my html body if a var abc = 0 else hide the button.

Could anyone help?

Here is what I have:

```
    .hidden {
  display: none;
}


var pass=0;
  function hideButton() {

    var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

      if (pass = 0) {
        hiddeninputs[i].style.display= "none";
      }
      else {
        hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "block" ;
      }

  }



    <form action="">
        <input type="button" value="Register" onclick='window.location.href="#page2"' onload="hideButton()"> <br />
    </form>
```

Comment: When you update the variable to be equal to 0, show the button, and when you update it to be anything other than 0, hide the button.

Comment: Maybe.  Show us some code.

Comment: Does that work, or not work? What's the problem you want us to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would give your button an `id`:

```
<input type="button" id="btnRegister" value="Register" onclick='window.location.href="#page2"' onload="hideButton()">
```

If you have access to and are using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    function hideButton(){
        if(pass === 0){
            $("#btnRegister").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#btnRegister").hide();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

If you need to do this in plain Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideButton(){
        if(pass === 0){
            document.getElementById("btnRegister").style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("btnRegister").style.display="block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but do I put this between <script> tags? In the header?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so, check out my answer (I just updated it). It should go between the `<script>` tags and between the document ready block `$(function(){ // code here }); `

Comment: Thanks FastTrack. I must be doing something wrong because its not working for me :(

Comment: @user2110655 Do you need to do this in straight Javascript, or can you use jQuery?

Comment: @user2110655 Check out my edits in my answer above... I put the solution in both jQuery and Javascript, depending on what you need. Make sure you add an `id` to your button (like I show above).

Answer (score 2):

jQuery [toggle takes a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) for show or hide

```
var $ele = $("#button"); //for your snippet
var abc = $("#abc").val();

$ele.toggle(abc === 0);
```

Comment: Good answer, but I've never been a fan of convoluted code... and THAT (although part of jQuery) is convoluted.

Comment: In what way is that 'convoluted'?

Comment: You know, I've never done a boolean comparison in a function call...but I really like the one-line quality of this. +1 I don't know that the average coder would understand what is happening here, but a one-line comment would probably be sufficient to explain.

Comment: @DavidThomas it's convoluted because looking at `$ele.toggle(abc === 0);` doesn't tell me anything. Toggle means what? You have no idea from just reading that code. Code should be as self-documenting as possible - and `toggle` is not at all self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function button() {
  var abc = parseInt($("#abc").val(), 10);
  if(abc === 0) {
      $("#button").show();
  } else {
      $("#button").hide();
  }
}
```